# What will my un-malloced pointer point to here?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have simplified my mailbox to the code below.
I have a SetMsg(), GetMsg() and ClearMsg() function.
At SetMsg(), my intention is to store the message until GetMsg() is called, at which point the stored message is returned to caller and, again, my intention is to convert the previously stored message to NULL.

But since I'm not `malloc`-ing anything, I wonder if it is perfectly safe to store the message in `ptr_Msg` like I do below? Since I have no control over what happens to the memory of which `msg` is stored at after I've "saved" it to `ptr_Msg`, isn't it possible that the memory of `msg` is later allocated by som other variable, while I still point to that adress? Or does my `static` in the declaration of `ptr_Msg`? save the day?

For example, `msg` carries the member `signal` when sent in to `SetMsg()`, and I store it in `ptr_Msg`. Then, outside of the scope of this function, `msg` changes its value of `signal`. If I then receive a `GetMsg()`, will I return the new value of `signal` or the value it had when it reached `SetMsg()`?

Should I instead do something like this? In `SetMsg()`

```
Msg* tmp = (Msg*) msg;
ptr_Msg = (Msg*) malloc(sizeof *tmp);
memcpy(ptr_Msg, tmp, sizeof *tmp);
```

And then later in `ClearMsg()`

```
free(ptr_Msg);
ptr_Msg = NULL;
```

Current code:

```
typedef struct Msg {
    uint16_t signal;
} Msg_t;

static Msg_t* ptr_Msg = NULL;


bool GetMsg(char** msgData, uint16_t* sigNo) {
    *msgData = (char*) ptr_Msg;

    // Get message
    if (*msgData != NULL) {
        // do some stuff

        // and then
        ClearMsg();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool SetMsg(void* msg) {

    if (ptr_Msg!=NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    ptr_Msg = (Msg*) msg;

    return true;
}

void ClearMsg() {
    ptr_Msg = (Msg*) NULL;
}
```

EDIT and possible answer:
I managed to get this tested and surely, it didn't hold water.
I've changed the code to the folowing and it seems to work. I've marked parts with "<=== new code section ===>".

Is it correct/safe use of malloc and free?

```
typedef struct Msg {
    uint16_t signal;
} Msg_t;

static Msg_t* ptr_Msg = NULL;


bool GetMsg(char** msgData, uint16_t* sigNo) {
    *msgData = (char*) ptr_Msg;

    // Get message
    if (*msgData != NULL) {
        // do some stuff

        // and then
        ClearMsg();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool SetMsg(void* msg) {

    if (ptr_Msg!=NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    // <=== new code section ===>
    ptr_Msg = malloc(sizeof *ptr_Msg);        
    memcpy(ptr_Msg, (Msg_t*) msg, sizeof *ptr_Msg);
    // <===  ===>    
    return true;
}

void ClearMsg() {
    // <=== new code section ===>
    free(ptr_Msg);
    // <===  ===>
    ptr_Msg = (Msg*) NULL;
}
```

Comment: `memcpy(&ptr_Msg, &tmp, sizeof *tmp);` looks wrong. I suspect you want `memcpy(ptr_Msg, tmp, sizeof *tmp);`

Comment: @Sean You're right.. edited. Also, I put some effort in accessing `msg` and altering it's content after `SetMsg()` but before `GetMsg()` and sure enough, the "stored" message `ptr_Msg` was altered. I've implemented the way I suggested myself and it works. Gonna give some time for others to explain in a better way.. or downvote and close as duplicate ;)

Comment: The code doesn't compile because of `break;`.

Comment: @harper sorry!! Missed that during "simplification" of code. Edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a complicated wrapper around a single, file scope variable `ptr_Msg`. The functions defined an interface. This interface is a contract with the caller about the ownership of the data that is referenced by the pointer `ptr_Msg`. It's impossible to say if you should need to copy the data instead of storing a pointer as long as the contract is unknown. With the current implementation the caller is responsible that the life time of the data lasts at least for the time while the pointer references the data. If you need a container (or mailbox) that is responsible to store some data, you need to copy the data with memcpy of similar.

The main question is, what do you want?
What is the contract?
What is stored?

Comment: Exactly, I want to store the msg in `ptr_Msg` regardless of the life time of data `msg` that came in through `SetMsg()`.

Comment: `msg` is a parameter to `SetMsg`. It has the type "pointer". If you want to store that pointer you're done.

Comment: Say, I want to store the value of `signal` that is a member of `msg`, through the struct `Msg_t`

Comment: @niCkcAMel This should be part of the question. Don't forget to make it visible in your question what you have changed if you add important info to the question.

Comment: yeah, the question was so young I figured I just slip in the edit incognito.